# AWS API Gateway access private API Gateway in another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to have a (public) AWS API Gateway in account A access a private API Gateway sitting in account B?

If so, how is this configured?

This [article](https://www.levvel.io/resource-library/aws-api-gateway-for-multi-account-architecture) describes the setup, but uses a VPC within account A with an NLB and VPC peering.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: What is your definition of private? Do you mean private API Gateway that resides in a VPC?

Comment: Do you have VPC peering set up between account A and B? Else, does API GW in account B allow access to a VPC in account A in its resource policy?

Comment: Yes that's correct, if you image an architecture of many backend microservices (perhaps one per account or some shared in a single account) and one public API Gateway in a central account that exposes a subset of those APIs, for centralised api key/usage plan management.

Comment: I've linked an article that describes a VPC peering approach, I wondered if there are any alternatives that may scale better? i.e. as the number of backend service accounts grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the VPC peering approach, you can implement your use case using Lambda functions (placed in a VPC in account A) and the private API in account B allowing the VPC in account A access in its resource policy. Also note, the two VPCs should be in the same region for this setup.

How it would look:

- Public API in account A has integration set up with a Lambda function in the same account
- Lambda function is placed inside a VPC (let's call this VPC A)
- Private API in account B allows VPC A access in its [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html)
- Lambda function in account A should now be able to invoke the private API and return the required data