# AWS API Gateway integration with another API Gateway in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Imagine a setup where we have one Public API Gateway for fronting APIs in Account A. And in the back-end we have multiple services Account B & Account C. These services in individual accounts (B & C) are Lambda fronted by Private API Gateway.

Is it possible to integrate Public API Gateway with cross account Private API gateway?

I couldn't find any documentation on how this can be done. Found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221294/aws-api-gateway-access-private-api-gateway-in-another-account?rq=1), but the solution proposed there is by adding another lambda function in Account A to access API Gateway in Account B. Is there any better approach available? Would it be possible to create VPC Endpoint for Private API Gateways and create VPC Links in Public Gateway to route requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage access to your APIs by creating IAM permission policies to control who can or cannot create, update, deploy, view, or delete API entities. A policy is attached to an IAM user representing your user, to an IAM group containing the user, or to an IAM role assumed by the user.
[Control cross-account access to your API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-cross-account-lambda-auth-and-integration.html)

Comment: Access control is fine. The problem is how to even configure Public API to forward requests to cross account Private API.